# Flex compiled file (lex.yy.c) cannot find header/dependencies and compiles strangely

Tags: c++, c, compilation, header, flex-lexer

I am trying to compile a small lexical analyser application with Flex.
the lex.yy.c file is indeed generated, yet when I add it to my project in Visual Studio,
it produces tens of errors, claiming to not recognize structs and functions I defined in
a related header.

This header is #include'd in the file I send to Flex.

Additionally, when I try to work out those errors, it seems that some of the errors' origins are in the
Flex Scripts txt file I used to generate the lex.yy.c in the first place or other files which have nothing to do with my project such as flexskel.cc

Why does it try to compile non related files?
I am working with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 10.

Here is a short version of the file I send to Flex:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TokenInterface.h"
int lineCounter = 0;
%}
DIGIT   [0-9]
LETTER [a-zA-Z] 
%%
"START_PROG" 
{
storeTokenInList(yytext, lineCounter, START_PROG);
fprintf(yyout,"\nSTART_PROG: %s\n",mostRecentToken->lexema);
return;
}                                                               
"END_PROG"          
{
storeTokenInList(yytext, lineCounter, END_PROG);
fprintf(yyout,"\nEND_PROG: %s\n",mostRecentToken->lexema);
return;
 }                                                           %%     

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
token* mostRecentToken;
createEmptyTokenList();
yyin = fopen("c:\\Flex\\input.txt","r");
yyout = fopen("c:\\Flex\\output.txt","w");
yylex();
mostRecentToken = backToken();

while (mostRecentToken->tokenType != EOF)
{
    yylex();
    mostRecentToken = backToken();
}
printf("Flex Out.\n");
}
```

Comment: Okay your flex program is completely off if it is INDEED written the way you have posted it.  I am going to FIX the lex code for you so that it will compile properly.

I can help you with the coding but PLEASE post it EXACTLY the way you have it written in the file.  If you have difficult with formatting here use pastebin.com and paste it there

Comment: also can you paste your TokenInterface.h code as well?

Comment: Thank you very much for you comments, I eventually found out the error was mine - I misused some variables in my Flex Scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my error:

The variable mostRecentToken is declared in the main function.
It is used in the Flex Scripts as well, yet Flex does not know any of the variables declared in the main func.

I replaced the mostRecentToken in the script with yytext and voila.

Thanks again everyone :)